# Access-Control-Allow-Origin being ignored

Tags: node.js, cors

I could really use some help.

I've followed the [advice in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13148080) so that my server is sending Access-Control-Allow-Origin headers for whatever origin is requesting a particular resource. Sadly I'm still getting the same `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://requestedUrl. Origin https://originUrl is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin` error in the browser.

The header is definitely being set. I've copied the provided middleware code-snippet exactly and it is definitely being run. Running out of ideas to look into.

Any thoughts would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the headers that you receive in the browser? Use the dev tools of whatever browser you are using to see them.

Comment: Can you post the middlewares you use ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was twofold.

Firstly I wasn't sending Access-Control-Allow-Credential. Secondly, once Access-Control-Allow-Credential is being sent, Access-Control-Allow-Origin cannot be *.